# Flutter Web pass Firebase Auth to HTML

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter, flutter-web

On a Flutter Web Application, I initialize Firebase in the index.html like below.

```
<body>
  <!-- Check type of device and block all mobile phone devices! Tablets should work -->
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- If you enabled Analytics in your project, add the Firebase SDK for Analytics -->
  <script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

  <!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
  <script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
  <script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-functions.js"></script>
  <script src="init-firebase.js" defer></script>
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js?v=3005614081');
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Further, I have an init-firebase.js for the Firebase config as per below.

```
// Initialize Firebase
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "...",
    projected: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "...",
    measurementId: "..."
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

This works all fine and within Dart I can access Firebase Auth, etc.

I wonder however how I can access Firebase Auth when I open a new HTML file within the application like example.html?

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    _showDocument();
    super.initState();
  }

  _showDocument() async {
    await ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
        'ExamplePage',
        (int viewId) => IFrameElement()
          ..src = 'https://example.com'
          ..style.border = 'none');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      child: HtmlElementView(viewType: 'ExamplePage'),
    ));
  }
}
```

In the example.html like below I would like to access Firebase data like Auth, Storage, etc for users who have authenticated in the Flutter Web App but I can't. Calling my init-firebase.js would init Firebase again.

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <title>Example</title>
    <script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-functions.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="init-firebase.js" defer></script> -->
</head>

<body>
    <div id="my-view" style="height: 95%; width: 100%;" oncontextmenu="return false;"></div>
    <script>
        // Access Firebase data like AUTH, Storage, Firestore here.....
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The Flutter Web App is still on the same tab and index.html and I am only opening another HTML window within that. Any way to pass Firebase down to HTML?

Comment: Hey Frank. Thanks for the reminder. Was still thinking of a solution and sometimes it takes a bit longer. Please see my comments below and please add any thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to pass a `FirebaseApp` instance (or services taken from that such as the database or auth) between pages. Each web page that loads in a browser is its own instance, and will need to load the Firebase services it uses.

Comment: I was wondering about that and thinking of a solution to my problem. In the end I agree that you can't pass the FirebaseApp instance. I am using now JavaScript Channels to communicate between the views to that the data I have to pass to Firebase is returned back first for the FirebaseApp instance and from there any actions are performed.